# Method call as a parameter of another method in Java

Tags: java, methods, nested

so i am required to do an assignment in which i follow JUnit test file to create all the code that i need(almost like a design doc), basicly its coding a vending machine, inside the test file there is this code right here

```
assertThat(snackMachine.chewingGums().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY - 1);
assertThat(snackMachine.chips().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY - 1);
assertThat(snackMachine.chocolates().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY - 1);
```

and i was scratching my head, looking at this, how can a method inside a class have a method inside it aswell, so chewingGums() has quantity() inside of it????, is this possible in java?, because i have looked all over, and i havent seen a way to implement it, like it shows here.

Comment: What do you mean *"a method inside it aswell"*? `snackMachine.chewingGums()` **returns something** that has a `quantity` method.

Answer (score 2):

`chewingGums` returns an object that has a `quantity` method.

```
chewingGums().quantity()
```

Would be the same as

```
Gum gum = chewingGums();
gum.quantity();
```

Where `Gum` is the type that `chewingGums` returns.

It's similar to this line:

```
new Scanner().nextInt();
```

`new Scanner()` evaluates to a `Scanner` object, then `nextInt` is called on that object. This isn't a great example since `Scanner` is a constructor, but it's the simplest method chaining example I could think of.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that it could be returning some kind of functional interface implementation (something similar to `Consumer`) with abstract method named `quantity`.

Comment: @it'sBritneyB I think that would complicate matters. Whatever object `chewingGums` returns will have a `quantity` method. It doesn't change much if that method is from an interface or a concrete implementation.

Comment: so would it look something like this? `public BigDecimal chewingGums() {
    public BigDecimal quantity() {}    
    
    }`

Comment: @3marproof No... The `chewingGum()` method returns **an instance of some type** which **has a method** named `quantity()`.

Comment: @3marproof No, unless `chewingGums` returns an instance of the class that it's in. Sec, I'll see if I can think of a good simple comparison example.

Comment: no its fine i understand now, so basicly chewinggum returns an object or a type that has quantity() method implemented, got it, thanks guys